# Activate the corresponding ribbon tool tab

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Programmatically select a shape on PowerPoint slides doesn't activate the corresponding ribbon tool tab.

The attached image shows that when selecting an "Audio Shape" manually, the ribbon tab of "Audio Tools" is then automatically visible. But when selecting the shape through a VBA code e.g. `oShp.Select`, the ribbon tab of "Audio Tools" will not visible.

[image]

Is there any special trick to make the corresponding ribbon tool tab visible when selecting a shape programmatically?

I need to access some commands through the SendKeys method as I can't/ don't know how to set some properties of the audio shape (e.g. audio fade-out duration, volume, starts).

[image]

**EDIT**

Further testing.
The following code will make the ribbon tab visible

```
Sub test()
    Dim pres As Presentation
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    
    Set pres = ActivePresentation
    Set sld = pres.Slides(1)
    Set shp = sld.Shapes(1)
    
    shp.Select
End Sub
```

However, if I add more lines after the select statement, the ribbon tab will not visible, e.g.

```
Sub test()
    Dim pres As Presentation
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    
    Set pres = ActivePresentation
    Set sld = pres.Slides(1)
    Set shp = sld.Shapes(1)
    
    shp.Select
    DoEvents
    SendKeys "%jn%v%{DOWN}", True 'Volume=low
    'SendKeys "%jn%u%{UP}", True ' Start:  play across slides
    SendKeys "%jn%o5~", True 'Fade out: 5s
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use `SendKeys`.

The code below will change some of the audio options.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape

    Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    Set shp = sld.Shapes("Recorded Sound")
    
    With shp.MediaFormat
        .FadeInDuration = 1000
        .FadeOutDuration = 1000
        .StartPoint = 0
        .EndPoint = 4000
        .Volume = 0.8
    End With

End Sub
```

I'll admit I haven't found how to Play Across Slides or Rewind after Playing.

Comment: How to set the property "Hide During Show" to True (ticked)?